# Why is the careers section only open to Programmers/Developers?

Tags: support, jobs

Looking at the first page of the careers section, I can see that 3/4 of all jobs are for pure developers, but the other 1/4 is for Linux Engineers, Product Managers, Program Managers, ...

So, I've got an extremely simple question:  "Why is the careers section only open to developers???" **:/**

<sub>**Some background:**</sub>

<sub>If you're not a Stack Exchange Inc. policy maker, please do be so kind as to refrain from answering as this is a pure policy question...  **:(**</sub>

<sub>Yes, I know I can still *look for jobs on careers* and then contact the companies directly... **>:)**</sub>

Comment: Is this more a 'this is what our clients are posting/paying us for' or is it a 'this is what the site limits our clients to posting'?

Comment: @MichaelT: I would say the latter...

Comment: @WillCole: I did look, but couldn't find anything... So thanks for the duplicate!  (instead of the normal whining and complaining that "*It's not a duplicate!"*  **;-)** (Original Q&A up-voted as well so that the next dummy like me can find it easier)